# Lightweight tool for generating random coordinates for specific region / country?

Tags: python, random, coordinates, geo

For now, I'm generating geo positions with only `random` module:

```
from random import uniform
geo_position =  (uniform(-90, 90), uniform(-180, 180))
```

Obviously, this method can produce a dot somewhere in the ocean or about it. So I want to be able to specify some region (e.g. Asia) or even country and get the dot from that area.

Are there any tools/snippets for this?

Comment: are you generating random positions on a sphere with uniform distributions ?!?

Comment: @Stéphane yep. Is it the wrong way?

Comment: Suppose you were to generate a random location in, say, Iceland. What would you want to be able to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, and the answer is pretty simple, so I think it will work in the most of the cases. All you need to do is to:

1. Download the databases of the cities ([link](https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database?pkit_lang=en), maxmind.com). It weights 33mb in .gz format and includes 3.173.959 cities with there names and coordinates.
2. Extract the `.txt` file and shuffle the lines. It can be done with a simple command `sort -R worldcitiespop.txt -o shuffled_cities.txt`
3. Select the random line and it's done! Here's a visualization for 100 randomly selected cities:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Had to do a similar thing, but wanted to be really uniformly spread in Europe in this case.

```
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter 

shp = shapefile.Reader('shapefiles/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp')
# Adjust for your case:
EU3 = ['ARM', 'BIH', 'BIH', 'CYP', 'DNK', 'IRL', 'AUT', 'EST', 'CZE', 'FIN' 
      , 'FRA', 'DEU', 'GRC', 'HRV', 'HUN', 'ISL', 'ITA', 'LTU', 'LVA', 'BLR'
      , 'MLT', 'BEL', 'AND', 'GIB', 'LUX', 'MCO', 'NLD', 'NOR', 'POL', 'PRT'
      , 'ROU', 'MDA', 'ESP', 'CHE', 'GBR', 'SRB', 'SWE', 'ALB', 'MKD', 'MNE'
      , 'SVK', 'SVN'] # 'TUR'
EU = [(boundary, record) for boundary, record in 
             zip(shp.shapes(), shp.records()) if record[2] in EU3]

# Adjust the borders 
count = Counter()  # small optimisation to check for big shapes first
def sample(shapes, min_x=-11, max_x=26, min_y=37, max_y=71):
    while True:
        point = (np.random.uniform(min_x, max_X), np.random.uniform(min_y, max_y)) 
        for boundary, record in sorted(shapes, key=lambda x: -count[x[1][2]]):
            if Point(point).within(shape(boundary)): 
                count[record[2]] += 1
                return point
```

This gives you the samples you want. Below a plot of a 5000 point sample from Europe. To obtain one sample use

```
sample(EU)
```

[image: Showcase]

Comment: Could you please edit your code regarding what 'interval_x' and 'interval_y' mean?

Comment: Changed the line :)

Comment: could you also please add the code to plot the 5000 points as well? I am having trouble with the legend showing wrong countries. So would be very helpful if you could add the code for plotting the 5000 points as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar use case and since I did not find any library available, I developed this python library: PyCristoforo. Github link: https://github.com/AleNegrini/PyCristoforo

Version 1.0.0 only supports European countries, but I plan to release other countries soon.

Comment: Impressive. Can it be modified to get let's say n random coordinates on Indian ocean or Arctic ocean?

Comment: I am currently not maintaining the project any more due to lack of time. However, you can fork it :)